# Thumbnail close button is not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple images using a form. Selecting multiple images, all the image Thumbnails are displayed with close icon. If I click the close icon, the Thumbnail disappears but the number of selected images did not decreases.

Suppose, I select 5 images, 5 image Thumbnails are displayed with a close icon. When I click the close icon, 4 Thumbnails are displayed but the number of selected images still remains 5.

I have submitted my script and HTML code below.

thank you all...

**HTML**

```
<div class="upload__box">
      <div class="upload__btn-box">
          <label class="form-label">Select Images</label>
          <input name="image_mul[]" type="file" class="form-control upload__inputfile" id="" multiple accept="image/*">
      </div>
      <div class="upload__img-wrap"></div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  ImgUpload();
});

function ImgUpload() {
  var imgWrap = "";
  var imgArray = [];

  $('.upload__inputfile').each(function () {
    $(this).on('change', function (e) {
      imgWrap = $(this).closest('.upload__box').find('.upload__img-wrap');
      var maxLength = $(this).attr('data-max_length');
      var files = e.target.files;
      var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
      var iterator = 0;
      filesArr.forEach(function (f, index) {

    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
      return;
    }

    if (imgArray.length > maxLength) {
      return false
    } else {
      var len = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        if (imgArray[i] !== undefined) {
          len++;
        }
      }
      if (len > maxLength) {
        return false;
      } else {
        imgArray.push(f);

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          var html = "<div class='upload__img-box'><div style='background-image: url(" + e.target.result + ")' data-number='" + $(".upload__img-close").length + "' data-file='" + f.name + "' class='img-bg'><div class='upload__img-close'></div></div></div>";
          imgWrap.append(html);
          iterator++;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    }
  });
});


 });
  $('body').on('click', ".upload__img-close", function (e) {
    var file = $(this).parent().data("file");
    for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
      if (imgArray[i].name === file) {
        imgArray.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: I assume that the `len` variable is used to show how many images have been selected? If this is the case, you are not decrementing `len` in the remove image script.

Comment: Can you please suggest where should I add the code? And how to decrement the value of len?

Comment: Can you confirm that the `len` variable is what you are using to show how many items are selected, or are you using something else such as imgArray.len()?